# Migrar de Python2 a Python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, azure

Solicito apoyo migrando la versión que actualmente viene instalada en "Azure" al momento de crear una aplicación en **Django** en "**Kudu Engine**".

En la siguiente imagen se muestra la version instalada "**Python 2.7.15**".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mil gracias

Answer (score 2):

Disculpame ya lo solucione de la siguiente manera.

1. Paso: Agregar en la opcion: "**Extensiones**", opcion: "Agregar", "Python 3.6.4 x86". como lo muestro en la siguiente imagen.

[image: Microsoft Azure]

2. Paso: Dirigirme a la opcion "**Configuracion de la aplicacion**", opcion: "Asignaciones de controlador" y agrego en

   - EXTENSIÓN: fastCgi
   - PROCESADOR DE SCRIPT: D:\home\python364x86\python.exe
   - ARGUMENTOS: D:\home\python364x86\wfastcgi.py

como lo muestro en la siguiente imagen.

[image: Microsoft Azure]

3. Paso: Y despues comprobe la solucion en "Kudu" de la siguiente forma.

[image: Kudu Engine]